# Google Analitics API error: Request is missing required authentication credential

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm trying to get info from [google analitics from api](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/rest/v4/reports/batchGet?authuser=1) but always get this error:

[image]

I've made OAuth2 and got token, but I don't know where to put it.
Can someone explain what have I done wrong?

Comment: please edit your question and include your code

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are having is that the call has not bee authorized.  To access private user data you need permission which means you need to send a properly authorized access token along with your request

This is sent as an Authorization header,  something like this.

curl -X POST -H "Authorization: bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxxx" "https://analyticsreporting.googleapis.com/v4/reports:batchGet"